# Rolling TTRPG Dice in Excel without VBA? Need something like a FOR() loop

Tags: excel, for-loop, dice

What is the best way to roll TTRPG dice in Excel (i.e. different QTYs of dice at once)? I was thinking of using `RAND*__` or `RANDBETWEEN*__`, but I realized that does not roll individual dice, it would simply multiply a single roll by the number of dice.

It doesn't look like there's a FOR() loop function anywhere in Excel (outside of a VBA macro). So, how could I roll things like `4d6` or `8d8` via something like a for loop:

4d6 would be something like:

```
Int Result
FOR(1 to 4)
    Result += RANDBETWEEN(1,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is available in older versions of Excel, but in Office 365 you can use the function `RANDARRAY`

`=RANDARRAY(1, [number of dice], 1, [largest number on die], TRUE)`

This will fill the adjacent columns with a number of random rolls equal to the [number of dice] value in the above formula.

[image]

If you wrap this formula in a another function like SUM, MAX, MIN, etc, it will calculate it in the single cell and not spill into the adjacent columns.

Here's the final function I used for the below screenshot:

`=SUM(RANDARRAY(1, [number of dice], 1, [largest number on die], TRUE))`

[image]